# Combine one field in a JSON object array to comma-delimited string in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, linq

I have a JSON object array like this which is being given via AJAX from client side.

```
[{"aid":"6038","testid":"162","testtype":"0"},
{"aid":"6037","testid":"162","testtype":"1"},
{"aid":"5763","testid":"162","testtype":"0"},
{"aid":"5772","testid":"162","testtype":"1"},
{"aid":"5773","testid":"162","testtype":"1"}]
```

I've a server side class to deserialize the above JSON as below.

```
Public Class ComparisonAttributes
    Public testid, attributeid, testtype As Integer
End Class
```

So I deserialise the JSON as

```
 Dim ca() As ComparisonAttributes
 ca = js.Deserialize(Of ComparisonAttributes())(attributes)
```

So I've got the real JSON object array.

But my requirement is to combine all **aid** in the JSON object to a comma delimitted string based on a condition like **testtype=1**

So the result should be 6037,5772,5773

I was able to made that using a loop across the JSON object like this

```
For Each cad As ComparisonAttributes In ca
   ''' Here i did the condition check and append to a string array
Next
```

But I believe there is a one liner like we do combining rows in Datatable using LINQ or similar way without a loop

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ query like this maybe should help:

```
Dim result = ca.Where(Function(item) item.testtype = 1).Select(Function(item) item.aid).ToArray()
```

or something like:

```
Dim result = (From ca In item Where item.testtype = 1item.aid).ToArray()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this shows as error at the last integer portion
Dim result = ca.Where(Function(item) item.testtype = 1).Select(Function(item) item.attributeid).ToArray(Of Integer)()

Here at "Of Integer" having an error something like "enumerable is not generic and cannot have type arguments"

Comment: Try with implicit conversion. I just updated the answer